# Python script works but fails after compilation (Windows)

Tags: python, compilation, web-scraping, mechanize, python-requests

I am working on a script to scrape a website, the problem is that it works normally when I run it with the interpreter, however after compiling it (PyInstaller or Py2exe) it fails, it appears to be that mechanize / requests both fail to keep the session alive.

I have hidden my username and password here, but I did put them correctly in the compiled code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from sys import argv
import re
import logging

url = argv[1]
payload = {"userName": "real_username", "password": "realpassword"}
session = requests.session()
resp = session.post("http://website.net/login.do", data=payload)
if "forgot" in resp.content:
    logging.error("Login failed")
    exit()

resp = session.get(url)
soup = bs(resp.content)
urlM = url[:url.find("?") + 1] + "page=(PLACEHOLDER)&" + \
url[url.find("?") + 1:]
# Get number of pages
regex = re.compile("\|.*\|\sof\s(\d+)")
script = str(soup.findAll("script")[1])
epNum = int(re.findall(regex, script)[0])  # Number of EPs
pagesNum = epNum // 50
links = []
# Get list of links
# If number of EPs > 50, more than one page
if pagesNum == 0:
    links = [url]
else:
    for i in range(1, pagesNum + 2):
        url = urlM.replace("(PLACEHOLDER)", str(i))
        links.append(url)
# Loop over the links and extract info: ID, NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE
raw_info = []
for pos, link in enumerate(links):
    print "Processing page %d" % (pos + 1)
    sp = bs(session.get(link).content)
    table = sp.table.table
    raw_info.extend(table.findAll("td"))
epURL = "http://www.website.net/exchange/viewep.do?operation"\
"=executeAction&epId="
# Final data extraction
raw_info = map(str, raw_info)
ids = [re.findall("\d+", i)[0] for i in raw_info[::4]]
names = [re.findall("<td>(.*)</td", i)[0] for i in raw_info[1::4]]
start_dates = [re.findall("<td>(.*)</td", i)[0] for i in raw_info[2::4]]
end_dates = [re.findall("<td>(.*)</td", i)[0] for i in raw_info[3::4]]
emails = []
eplinks = [epURL + str(i) for i in ids]
print names
```

The error happens on the level of epNum variable, this means as I figured that the HTML page is not the one I requested, but it works normally on linux script and compiled, work on widows as script but fails when compiled.

Comment: Do you have any errors? Logs?

Answer (score 0):

The py2exe tutorial mentions that you need MSVCR90.dll, did you check its present on the PC?

Comment: Yes it is, the problem is with the python code, as I said neither mechanize nor requests are able to keep the session alive